# Failed to parse time string (2018-03-10 13:08:09.-708656) at position 24 (6): Unexpected character

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am getting this error sometimes then it goes away automatically. Unable to track why I am getting this error. And I think it get's fixed when the session expires. This is the error screen

```
(1/1) Exception
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2018-03-10 18:06:52.-955808) at position 24 (8): Unexpected character

in Carbon.php (line 408)
at DateTime->__construct('2018-03-10 18:06:52.-955808', object(DateTimeZone))
in Carbon.php (line 408)
at Carbon->__construct('2018-03-10 18:06:52.-955808', null)
in Carbon.php (line 457)
at Carbon::now()
in FileSessionHandler.php (line 70)
at FileSessionHandler->read('SEOHFptNtGSB4YmLTb7IAegTxX6EZcAFGB2wnvPZ')
in Store.php (line 96)
at Store->readFromHandler()
in Store.php (line 86)
at Store->loadSession()
in Store.php (line 70)
at Store->start()
in StartSession.php (line 103)
at StartSession->Illuminate\Session\Middleware\{closure}(object(EncryptedStore))
in helpers.php (line 964)
at tap(object(EncryptedStore), object(Closure))
in StartSession.php (line 104)
at StartSession->startSession(object(Request))
in StartSession.php (line 58)
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
```

Comment: Same. My code is working just fine and I suddenly got that error and i don't know what triggers it. I am using laravel 5.4

Comment: I am also using L-5.4

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23458. Seems to be a bug in Carbon.

Comment: same here on laravel 4.2 everything was working fine then suddenly this happened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this error is due to a carbon update as mentioned by @btl i surfed a bit on the internet , if you added a library or ran composer update that would probably be the source of the problem , if you have any old laravel projects go to $root/vendor/nesbot/ , you will find a carbon folder there copy and replace that in your current project that isnt working and it will be fixed.if you want i can upload my carbon folder to google drive or something for you to use.

hope this helps.

**EDIT**

for those who dont have older apps , you can find the carbon file which will fix the issue [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oiD6IFmrn1cWpPTjF9K0msW8B-Qrr1F5)

Comment: this solved the issue, please upload the carbon folder for future users.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you `strtotime` it, it solves the issue:

```
Carbon::parse(strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have any old laravel projects go to Project-Folder/vendor/nesbot/ , you will find a  carbon folder there copy and replace that in your current project folder. 
 That's the solution